# Get indexOf clicked button parent in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a function to add elements to array list and it worked successfully:

```
function add(){
  new_index = list.push("<div><button class='delete' 
onclick='delete_item()'>delete</button> 
  <p>"+input.value+"</p></div>");
}
```

I want do delete the element when i click `<button class='delete'></button>` by get the button parent index then splice it from array

I have tried this code but it does not work, can I get the parent index .. can someone help me?

```
function delete_item(){
  index = list.indexOf(this.parentElement);
  items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: `list` contains strings, `indexOf` will never find anything from the list, i.e. `index` will always be `-1`. You've to keep a list of the live element references, that should be updated where ever you actually insert the tags in `list` to the DOM.

Comment: Notice also, that `Array.push` returns the new length of the array, not the last index of its members. To get the last index, you need to decrement the result by one.

Comment: What does your HTML structure looks like? What is the parent of list here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with Jquery, with handlers and passing current element

```
function delete_item(el){
  index = list.indexOf(el.parentElement);
  items.splice(index, 1);
}

$('.delete').on('click',(el)=>{
delete_item(el.currentTarget)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call rerender Dom after it. And in your case you must also use this.parentElement.parentElement. Because your button has a wrapper element.